# how to bypass 'dictionary changed size during iteration'

Tags: python, dictionary, heuristics

I'm writing a heuristic function for a problem that can be presented by a table (a tuple of tuples) and I'm starting with some random cells in my table which I give a 0 value, then adding 1 to its neighbors and so on - this value is later can be shown in a dictionary - where the key is the cell's coords and the value is its value. everytime I get into a new cell, I save it into my dic.

The problem - for this BFS-ish method which I made, I need some kind of a dynamic sized dictionary. There are some initial keys when I start iterating, then more are added when the code runs - and the code needs to check those new cells too. While I thought python will be able to handle this, I got a runtime error that says "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration"

```
    visitedCells = dict()
    for row in range(len(node.state)):
        for cell in range(len(node.state[0])):
            if STATEMENT:
                visitedCells[row, cell] = 0

    for cell, val in visitedCells.items():
        row = cell[0]
        col = cell[1]

        if STATEMENT:
            visitedCells[row + 1, col] = val + 1
        if STATEMENT:
            visitedCells[row - 1, col] = val + 1
        if STATEMENT:
            visitedCells[row, col + 1] = val + 1
        if STATEMENT:
            visitedCells[row, col - 1] = val + 1
```

I expect it to actually change size and continue during iteration. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Does `... continue during iteration` mean that if any new cels are created you want to visit them also? During the iteration do you intend to visit a cel more than once?  Does iteration order matter?

Comment: I’d want to visit every cell only once. I want to visit new cells also. Iteration order has to be BFS

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain a queue for the cells to visit and a separate dictionary which indicates the state of each cell:

```
queue = list(visitedCells.items())
while queue:
    row, col = queue.pop(0)

    if STATEMENT:
        visitedCells[row + 1, col] = val + 1
        queue.append((row + 1, col))
    ...
```

Comment: You might want to use a collections.deque for the queue.  Can cells be visited more than once with this?

Comment: @wwii If performance matters, certainly. If a cell can be visited more than once depends on the various `STATEMENT` while the algorithm doesn't prevent this scenario.

Comment: OP only wants to visit each cell once during an iteration, cells shouldn't be *blindly* added to the queue they should be qualified.

Comment: @wwii No problem, as I mentioned what is added to the queue depends on the `STATEMENT`. You can maintain an extra `set` that indicates if a cell has been visited already and only add it to the queue if `cell not in visited`. But that has nothing to do with *"how to bypass 'dictionary changed size during iteration'"* as per the question title.