# "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable" - Am I using queue wrong?

Tags: python, collections, queue, tuples, heuristics

I'm working on a code I already asked about here yesterday: [how to bypass 'dictionary changed size during iteration'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54156227/how-to-bypass-dictionary-changed-size-during-iteration?noredirect=1#comment95143377_54156227)

and as suggested, I moved to work on a BFS deque, but now, when I try to enter a cell details, it works (I can print the values and they come off right) but for some reason the compiler still tells me "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable". I looked some other articles here about this problem and they all talking about trying to reach a location inside an int as it was an array but its not what I do, I'm trying to reach a tuple. (I checked cell's type - it's a tuple)

Would be grateful for any help.

```
    for row in range(len(node.state)):
        for col in range(len(node.state[0])):
            if node.state[row][col] == DEST or node.state[row][col] == PDEST or node.state[row][col] == BDEST:
                visitedCells[row, col] = 0

    queue = collections.deque(visitedCells.items())

    while queue:
        cell, val = queue.pop()

        row = cell[0]
        col = cell[1]

        if ((row + 1, col) not in visitedCells and (node.state[row + 1][col] == EMPTY or node.state[row + 1][col]
                                                    == BOX or node.state[row + 1][col] == PLAYER or
                                                    node.state[row + 1][col] == ICE or node.state[row + 1][col]
                                                    == PICE or node.state[row + 1][col] == BICE)):
            visitedCells[row + 1, col] = val + 1
            queue.append((row + 1, col))
```

the traceback is:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\roniz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:/Users/roniz/PycharmProjects/AIp1t2/check.py", line 20, in run
    self.result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/roniz/PycharmProjects/AIp1t2/check.py", line 64, in <lambda>
    result = check_problem(p, (lambda p: search.best_first_graph_search(p, p.h)), timeout)
  File "C:\Users\roniz\PycharmProjects\AIp1t2\search.py", line 257, in best_first_graph_search
    frontier.append(node)
  File "C:\Users\roniz\PycharmProjects\AIp1t2\utils.py", line 750, in append
    bisect.insort(self.A, (self.f(item), item))
  File "C:\Users\roniz\PycharmProjects\AIp1t2\utils.py", line 361, in memoized_fn
    val = fn(obj, *args)
  File "C:\Users\roniz\PycharmProjects\AIp1t2\ex1.py", line 128, in h
    row = cell[0]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: You append a new tuple here: `queue.append((row + 1, col))`, **missing a value**, your dictionary items at the top are `((row, col), value)` tuples with a *nested* tuple. You pop `cell, val` from the queue, then index `cell`, so for the above append, that'd be `row + 1` for `cell`, and `col` for `val`. `row + 1` is not a tuple.

Comment: and python is usually very good about catching errors like this. youre very likely ending up with a `some_int[some_index]` somewhere.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - fixed, thx - added traceback

Answer (score 1):

You start your queue with `((row, cell), value)` tuples:

```
queue = collections.deque(visitedCells.items())
```

but then append only `(row, cell)` tuples to the queue while processing:

```
queue.append((row + 1, col))
```

This means that the line

```
cell, val = queue.pop()
```

is given just two integers, for `cell` and `val`. You need to append the value too:

```
queue.append(((row + 1, col), val + 1))
```

or alter your queue to only store `(row, col)` tuples and get the values from your `visitedCells` dictionary.